# Logical statement for f not to be continuous at a point a ∈ R.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, continuity

so the question is :

```
A function f : R → R is continuous at a point a ∈ R means:
∀ϵ > 0, ∃δ > 0 such that |x − a| < δ −→ |f(x) − f(a)| < ϵ.
Using the syntax of logic, define what it means for f not to be continuous at a
point a ∈ R.
```

and this is the answer I came up with:

```
~(∀ϵ > 0, ∃δ > 0 such that |x − a| < δ −→ |f(x) − f(a)| < ϵ.)
=> ∃ϵ <= 0, ∀δ <= 0 such that |x-a| < δ ^ ~|f(x) - f(a)| >= ϵ
```

** I used `~` as negation

Not sure if the answer is right, so I would appreciate it if you could correct me and explain where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of a problem. You should get

$$
\exists\epsilon>0,~\forall \delta > 0 ~~\text{s.t.}~~  |x-a|<\delta\land|f(x)-f(a)|\geq \epsilon
$$

When you negate a quantifier, you switch from universal to existential (and vice versa), you don't change the domain of discourse, and you negate the propositional function expressed. So, for example, the negation of $\forall n \in \mathbb{N},~P(n)$ is $\exists n\in \mathbb{N},\lnot P(n)$.

Comment: can you explain why you got the answer you did? so I am assuming we do not negate inequality signs? shouldnt `(|x − a| < δ −→ |f(x) − f(a)|)` be negated to `( ~(|x − a| < δ) ^ |f(x) − f(a)|)`?

Comment: The conditional $a\to b$ is logically equivalent to $\lnot a\lor b$, so by applying De Morgan's, we get $\lnot(a\to b) = \lnot(\lnot a\lor b) = a \land \lnot b$. In our case, $a$ is $|x-a|<\delta$ and $b$ is $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but wouldnt negating a→b translate to a∧¬b? ===== nevermind, just saw that you explained it :)

Comment: That is exactly what I said. Like... exactly. xD === you got it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Break it into parts.

Continuous means that "for all $\epsilon > 0$, there's a $\delta > 0$ such that you can get close enough". So discontinuous means that "there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that no matter which $\delta > 0$ you choose, you are *not* close enough (i.e., for all $\delta > 0$, you are not close enough".

What does "close enough" mean again? It means that "for all $x \in D$, $|x - c| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$". The negation of that is "there exists some $x$ such that $|x - c| < \delta$, but $|f(x) - f(c)| \ge \epsilon$". ($D$ is the domain of the function)

Putting it all together: $f$ is discontinuous at $c$ if:
$$\exists \epsilon > 0 \ \forall \delta > 0 \ \exists x \in D \ \left( |x - c| < \delta \wedge |f(x) - f(c)| \ge \epsilon \right) $$